# как сделать перенаправление в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Требуется, чтобы по урлу localhost/admin/ был задействован файл index.php (echo 'в админке!') в папке app/admin (папка app корневая). Подскажите плиз как это сделать в .htaccess

Не работает:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin/$  /admin/index.php [L]
```

Выдает 500 ошибку. Такая директива `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]` работает! Использую сборку MAMP

Comment: Добавте то, что у вас уже установленно. И что отображаеться. Какой веб-сервер используеться ( и используется ли вообще что-то )

Comment: поправил информацию

Comment: А куда смотрит хост? 'DocumentRoot` ?

Comment: на директрию app

Comment: попробуте поменять `^admin/$` на `^admin/.*$`

Comment: если так `RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ /admin/index.php [L]` - internal server error; если так `RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ admin/index.php [L]` - 500 ошибка;  если так `RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ index.php [L]` - ок (но это не то, что нужно)

Comment: 500 ошибка - a что говорит сервер? ( логи ошибок )

Comment: спасибо, за наводку. да действительно там нашел синтаксическую ошибку. теперь все работает!